# Enable only current date till next 30 days - bootstrap datepicker

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

In rails 3.2.13 project, I am using bootstrap datepicker plugin. Right now calender is displaying the current date by disabling the previous dates. Now I need to restrict the calender to select the current date + next 30 days only.

I am using below code to disable the previous date,

```
function currentDatePicker(id){
var nowTemp = new Date();
var now = new Date(nowTemp.getFullYear(), nowTemp.getMonth(), nowTemp.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

 $('#' + id).datepicker({
    format: "yyyy-mm-dd",
    onRender: function(date) {
        return date.valueOf() < now.valueOf() ? 'disabled' : '';
    }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**In Bootstrap datepicker Set Current date Use:** `startDate: new Date()` it desible previous date.

**Set next 30 days use:** `endDate: '+30d'` It shows only 30 days from the current date

here the example code:

> ```
> $('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
>   startDate: new Date(), // controll start date like startDate: '-2m' m: means Month
>   endDate: '+30d'
>
> });
> ```

Comment: How to exclude weekend from this 30 days?

Answer (score 4):

Try [maxDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-maxDate)

```
$('#' + id).datepicker({ maxDate: "+30d" });
```

or

```
$('#' + id).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", "+30d" );
```

---

Updated after OP's comment

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/xzH4b/)</kbd>

```
$('#' + id).datepicker({
    maxDate: "+30d",
    minDate:0
});
```

[minDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate)

Comment: Can i disable the previous dates from this function??

Comment: bootstrap datepicker will not accept maxDate, moreover previous dates are not disabling.

Comment: he need bootstrap date-picker but in your fiddle have jquery date-picker.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    startDate: 0,
    endDate: '+30d'
});
```

Comment: bootstrap datepicker will not accept maxDate, moreover previous dates are not disabling.

Answer (score -1):

Try this  its working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/1wsf97pt/

```
$(function () {
    $("#Id").datepicker({

        minDate: new Date,
        onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
            try {
                $.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', dateText);
            } catch (e) {

                alert(e);

            };
        }
    });
});
```